# Using a loop (or vectorisation) to subset a list by multiple elements in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a list of 3 `data.frame`s:

```
my_list <- list(a = data.frame(value = c(1:5), class = c(letters[1:3],"a", "b")), b = data.frame (value = c(6:1),class=c(letters[1:4],"a", "b")),c=data.frame(value = c(1:7),class = c(letters[5:1],"a", "b")))

my_list

$a
  value class
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     3     c
4     4     a
5     5     b

$b
  value class
1     6     a
2     5     b
3     4     c
4     3     d
5     2     a
6     1     b

$c
  value class
1     1     e
2     2     d
3     3     c
4     4     b
5     5     a
6     6     a
7     7     b
```

I want to go in to each list and subset them by  letters `a` and `b` from the `class` column:

```
wanted_sub_class <- c("a", "b")
```

and then put the results in a list  of `my_list` per `class`.

**Edit** - Expected output:

```
$a class a
    value class
       1     a
       4     a

$a class b 
    value class
       2     b
       5     b

$b class a
    value class
      4     a
      2     a

$b class b
   value class
      5     b
      1     b
$c class a
  value class
    5     a
    6     b

$c class b
  value class
     4     b
     7     b
```

I've tried to do it with a double loop:

```
result <- list()

for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  for (j in wanted_sub_class {

    result [[i]] <- subset(my_list[[i]], my_list[[i]]$class == j)

  }
}
```

This should give me 6 list elements (as per expected output) but it only gives 3 and only of element `b`.

**Ideally, however, if it's actually possible, I want to put the results in a list of `my_list` per `class`. So I want to keep the structure of the 3 data.frames in the list and then have a list with in that with the data of  class `a` and `b` -  Otherwise, a list of six will work**

I understand loops aren't ideal but I can't really get my head around vecortisation (e.g. using lapply). I would appreciate an answer for both loop (if it's possible) and vectorization.

Comment: Try `lapply(my_list, function(x) { subset(x, class %in% c("a", "b")) })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `purrr` from the Hadleyverse family of packages

```
library(purrr)
my_list %>% 
      map(~ .[.$class %in% wanted_sub_class,])
#$a
#   value class
#1     1     a
#2     2     b

#$b
#  value class
#1     4     a
#2     3     b

#$c
#  value class
#4     4     b
#5     5     a
```

---

Or if the output needs to have only 'a' and 'b' `list` elements

```
library(dplyr)
my_list %>%
       bind_rows %>%
       filter(class %in% wanted_sub_class) %>% 
       split(., .$class)
#$a
#  value class
#1     1     a
#3     4     a
#6     5     a

#$b
#  value class
#2     2     b
#4     3     b
#5     4     b
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's update

```
my_list %>%
       map(~ .[.$class %in% wanted_sub_class,]) %>%
       map(~split(.x, seq_len(nrow(.x)))) %>%
       do.call("c", .)
#$a.1
#  value class
#1     1     a

#$a.2
#  value class
#2     2     b

#$b.1
#  value class
#1     4     a

#$b.2
#  value class
#2     3     b

#$c.1
#  value class
#4     4     b

#$c.2
#  value class
#5     5     a
```

Or using the `bind_rows` approach

```
my_list %>%
    bind_rows %>%
    filter(class %in% wanted_sub_class) %>% 
    split(., seq_len(nrow(.)))
```

#### Update2

If we need a `for` loop

```
result <- setNames(vector('list', length(my_list)), names(my_list))
for(i in seq_along(my_list)){
  result[[i]] <- subset(my_list[[i]], class %in% wanted_sub_class)
  result[[i]] <- split(result[[i]], 1:nrow(result[[i]]))
 }
```

#### Update3

For the new output format

```
 my_list %>% 
     bind_rows(.id = "id")  %>%
     filter(class %in% wanted_sub_class) %>% 
     split(., list(.$id, .$class))
```

Or using the `for` loop

```
result <- setNames(vector('list', length(my_list)), names(my_list))
for(i in seq_along(my_list)){
  result[[i]] <- subset(my_list[[i]], class %in% wanted_sub_class)
  result[[i]] <- split(result[[i]], result[[i]]$class, drop = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is OP desired output

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  You also showed the same output in your post.

Comment: Yes that was my initial understanding of his request but after re-reading it, I think the second part of my answer is what OP wants.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  The OP didn't show the expected output, so I don't know.  I am following his line `I want to go in to each list and subset them by letters a and b from the class column:`

Comment: Yeah that's what I initially thought too. But hey, let's wait and see if he provides feedback.

Comment: I like the approach with `bind_rows` instead of `data.table::melt` +1

Comment: @Bonono I updated the post.  Please check if this helps

Comment: @Bonono  If you need the nesting, then remove the last step i.e. `do.call("c", .)`

Comment: @Bonono Updated with a `for` loop.

Comment: @akrun, I realised that your answer only works if data frame only contained one element of each class within it. I've edited the question and code to include at least 2. I've also taken away the correct answer is it would otherwise be misleading. thank you for your attention

Answer (score 4):

> I want to go in to each list and subset them by letters `a` and `b` from
>   the `class` column

Should you want to subset your list of `data.frame`s by `class` you could simply do:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) { subset(x, class %in% c("a", "b")) })
```

Which gives:

```
#$a
#  value class
#1     1     a
#2     2     b
#
#$b
#  value class
#1     4     a
#2     3     b
# 
#$c
#  value class
#4     4     b
#5     5     a
```

---

**Update**: After re-reading your question, from what I understand, you would prefer to reshape your actual list by `class`:

> Ideally, however, I want to put the results in a list of `my_list` per
>   `class` but I don't know how to do this in a loop.

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

data.table::melt(my_list) %>%
  filter(class %in% c("a", "b")) %>%
  select(class, value) %>%
  split(as.character(.$class))
```

Which gives:

```
#$a
#  class value
#1     a     1
#3     a     4
#6     a     5
#
#$b
#  class value
#2     b     2
#4     b     3
#5     b     4
```

---

As per mentionned by  @Sumedeh (in a now deleted comment), you could also use `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
my_list %>% 
  map_df(function(x) x[x$class %in% c("a", "b"), ]) %>% 
  split(.$class)
```

Which gives:

```
#$a
#  value class
#1     1     a
#3     4     a
#6     5     a

#$b
#  value class
#2     2     b
#4     3     b
#5     4     b
```

Comment: I didn't see your purrr approach while I posted the answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to reshape it but keep the original list structure of the 3 `data.frame`s and have a list of class `a` and class `b` nested within each one