# How to access all lists within lists with a loop

Tags: r, list, indexing, subset

This is a follow-up question from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974053/how-to-access-all-lists-within-lists-with-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment65301422_38974053) where I wanted to create a list within a list and now I want to be able to access the nested list and peform functions in it too.

I have a list of 3 that has a list of two within it:

```
    my_list

    structure(list(a = structure(list(a = structure(list(value = c(1L, 
4L), class = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
"class"), row.names = c(1L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), b = structure(list(
    value = c(2, 1), class = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "class"
), row.names = c(2L, 5L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a", 
"b")), b = structure(list(a = structure(list(value = c(6, 1), 
    class = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "class"), row.names = c(1L, 
5L), class = "data.frame"), b = structure(list(value = c(5, 1
), class = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "class"), row.names = c(2L, 
6L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a", "b")), c = structure(list(
    a = structure(list(value = 5:6, class = structure(c(1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "class"), row.names = 5:6, class = "data.frame"), b = structure(list(
        value = c(4, 1), class = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
        "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "class"), row.names = c(4L, 7L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a", 
"b"))), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"))

    $a
    $a$a
      value class
        1     a
        4     a

    $a$b
      value class
       2     b
       1     b


    $b
    $b$a
      value class
        6     a
        1     a

    $b$b
      value class
        5     b
        1     b


    $c
    $c$a
      value class
        5     a
        6     a

    $c$b
      value class
        4     b
        1     b
```

I want to `subset` each nested list **with a loop** by `value != 1` so that the resulting list looks like this:

```
my_list
$a
        $a$a
          value class
            4     a

        $a$b
          value class
           2     b



        $b
        $b$a
          value class
            6     a


        $b$b
          value class
            5     b



        $c
        $c$a
          value class
            5     a
            6     a

        $c$b
          value class
            4     b
```

With the below code, I can only access `list [[1]][[1]]`, `list[[2]][[2]]` and `list[[3]][[3]]`. How do I access the others with a loop and apply the `subset` function?

```
for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  my_list[[i]][[i]] <- subset(my_list[[i]][[i]],my_list[[i]][[i]]$value=1) 
 }
```

Comment: I notice that you didn't link to the question you asked yesterday on this topic. If the two are different, please show how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954154/using-a-loop-or-vectorisation-to-subset-a-list-by-multiple-elements-in-a-vecto

Comment: Good idea, have edited it

Comment: Good spot - fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a nested `lapply` or with `rapply`

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) subset(y, value!=1)))
#$a
#$a$a
#  value class
#4     4     a

#$a$b
#  value class
#2     2     b


#$b
#$b$a
#  value class
#1     6     a

#$b$b
#  value class
#2     5     b


#$c
#$c$a
#  value class
#5     5     a
#6     6     a

#$c$b
#  value class
#4     4     b
```

Comment: I really should learn how to use lapply. Is it not possible to do it with a loop?

Comment: @Bonono You have a nested loop, one way would be to go through the nested loop by looping or convert it to a single dataset, filter the 'value' and then again reconvert back to the nested form (which is unnecessarily complicated)

Comment: I agree, it sounds ridiculous when you put it like that. Thank you for your help akrun, you've been amazing as always. I'll be sure to acknowledge you in my PhD!

Comment: @Bonono Thank you for your kind words

Comment: Praise given where it's due. I would like to know how to be able to loop through a  nested loop though as I like to learn. I imagine I would need to double loop it so that I could access  `list [[1]][[2]]` and `list[[2]][[1]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to know how to do a nested loop for this question - I had help to figure this out:

```
for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
  my_list[[i]][[j]] <- subset(my_list[[i]][[j]],my_list[[i]][[j]]$value!=1) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside the `subset`, you can just use `value !=1` i.e. `my_list[[i]][[j]] <- subset(my_list[[i]][[j]], value != 1)`